# How to change the color of the tabline of the vim-airline?

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline

I'm trying to make transparent the tabline of the vim-airline, as in the second picture. I'm using the `onedark` colorscheme. They don't have a color specific for that. They use the same color variable for the statusbar and the cursorline. So if I put the following command in my `init.vim`, I change all three (tabline, statusbar and cursorline):

```
let g:onedark_color_overrides = {
\ "cursor_grey": { "gui": "#2C323C", "cterm": "NONE", "cterm16": "0" },
\}
```

I don't want to change the color of the cursorline.

I'm able to get the result I want for a specific session, using:

```
:hi airline_tabfill ctermbg=NONE
```

But I don't want to do this every time I open neovim. It doesn't work putting this command in the `init.vim` file.

Doing a little research, I found some people that put this command in a file in the `~/.vim/after/` directory. As I'm using neovim, I've tried this approach creating a file in the `~/.config/nvim/after/` directory. But it did nothing. I've also tried the `~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/` directory, and got nothing.

Interestingly, if I put this command in a file in the `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/` directory, I get the result I want. However, in that way I need to create a file for every filetype I want this result and put that command. That is a horrible solution.

Any thought on how to do it in a more efficient way?

And can anyone tell me why I'm able to get this result putting the command `hi airline_tabfill ctermbg=NONE` in a file like `tex.vim` or `python.vim` in the `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/` directory but can't do it for all filetypes putting this command in a file in the `~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/` directory?

[image: Non-transparent tabline]

[image: Transparent tabline]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestions. I've tried all of the options you'd mentioned, but none of them seems to have worked. I've put `autocmd FileType * hi airline_tabfill ctermbg=NONE` and `autocmd ColorScheme * hi airline_tabfill ctermbg=NONE` before and after `colorscheme onedark`. But unortunely it didn't change anything.

Comment: I have airline and tried a couple things. I, too, couldn't change the highlight by just putting the statement in my vimrc but looking at the docs I found airline specific autocommands and this one seems to do the trick: `autocmd User AirlineAfterInit hi airline_tabfill ...`

Comment: If this works for you let me know and I'll post a formal answer. (Which I'd appreciate you accepting...before you disappear forever...which happens a lot with first time question posters. :D )

Comment: It worked! thank you so much, I really appreciate. Sure thing, I'll accept it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I alluded to in my (now deleted) comments this seemed to just be a matter of timing, i.e. you need some way to specify your `hi` customization such that it doesn't get clobbered by vim-airline's own setup.

Being a vim-airline user myself, I did `:h airline` then `/autocommands`. That quickly revealed that the plugin has five "user-defined" autocommands. Of the five, the one that seemed most likely to help was this one:

> **AirlineAfterInit** : after plugin is initialized, but before the statusline is replaced

*Source: `:h airline-autocommands`*

So I tried putting the following in my vimrc:

```
augroup HITABFILL
    autocmd!
    autocmd User AirlineAfterInit hi airline_tabfill ctermbg=NONE
augroup END
```

And lo and behold it worked. (The "user-defined" part I mentioned above is how I knew to use `User` here since it's not explicitly mentioned in that section of the docs.)

Comment: Yay, after 2 years I don't have anymore light grey on dark grey inactive tabs...

Comment: @RobM LOL. Yay, after 1 year I don't have zero upvotes on this answer... ;)  (And I just noticed I had a typo, too! The doc excerpt had one autocommand but the example used another.)